# iTunes 10, Win 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, itunes, itunes-10

I'm running Windows 7 64bit, and I'd like to update to iTunes 10.  However, I'm a little concerned, as I recall reading about the last two iTunes iterations both having more than their shared of problems with Win7x64.  Is anyone here using this combination, and did you have any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using iTunes 9 and now installed 10 with Win 7 x64 and never had any issue. 
As far as I know, there are no really big differences between x32 and x64, except because the x64 can address more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The "64-bit" iTunes installer is 64-bit, but the application itself is still 32-bit. So your issues are going to be the same as before, whatever they may have been.